# iOS: Sample Code or Examples for CGPDFContextAddDocumentMetadata

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, metadata

I need to embed some custom meta data to a PDF file using the Apple's Objective C SDK. Is there any working sample code available that does that?

What I need is very basic. Open an existing pdf and add some meta data and then save it.

Example of information stored will be like.... a customer's name, contact number, items ordered.

I saw that this "CGPDFContextAddDocumentMetadata" supports metadata but I don't know how the meta data look like and how is it used passed to this function.

Any help will be greatly appreciated...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata is metadata (of course, it is recommended by Adobe that you use XMP XML).  So long as you create a valid CFDataRef and pass it into arg two, you're pretty much good to go with anything.  For example, here's how to pass the string "Hello World" into a PDF's metadata:

```
void MakeAPDF()
{

    CGRect mediaRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 600);
    // use your own rect instead

    CFMutableDataRef result = CFDataCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
    CGDataConsumerRef PDFDataConsumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData(result);

    // mark the PDF as coming from your program
    CFMutableDictionaryRef auxInfo = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 1, NULL, NULL);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(auxInfo, kCGPDFContextCreator, CFSTR("Your Programs Name"));
    CFDictionaryRef auxillaryInformation = CFDictionaryCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, auxInfo);
    CFRelease(auxInfo);

    // create a context to draw into
    CGContextRef graphicContext = CGPDFContextCreate(PDFDataConsumer, &mediaRect, auxillaryInformation);
    CFRelease(auxillaryInformation);
    CGDataConsumerRelease(PDFDataConsumer);

    // actually make the call to embed your String
    NSString* str= @"Hello World";
    NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    CFDataRef cfdata = CFDataCreate(NULL, [data bytes], [data length]);

    CGPDFContextAddDocumentMetadata(graphicContext, cfdata);

    CGContextBeginPage(graphicContext, &mediaRect);
    // do your drawing, like this grey rectangle
    CGContextSetGrayFillColor(graphicContext, 0.5, 0.5);
    CGContextAddRect(graphicContext, mediaRect);
    CGContextFillPath(graphicContext);
    // end your drawing

    CGContextEndPage(graphicContext);
    CGContextFlush(graphicContext);
    CGPDFContextClose(graphicContext);    
}
```

An XMP file might look like this:

```
<?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 4.2.1-c041">
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <dc:format>application/pdf</dc:format>
  <dc:title>
    <rdf:Alt>
      <rdf:li />
    </rdf:Alt>
  </dc:title>
  <dc:description>
    <rdf:Alt>
      <rdf:li />
    </rdf:Alt>
  </dc:description>
  <dc:creator>
    <rdf:Seq>
      <rdf:li />
    </rdf:Seq>
  </dc:creator>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/">
  <pdf:Keywords />
  <pdf:Producer />
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
  <xmp:CreatorTool />
  <xmp:CreateDate>2011-02-10T11:41:05+02:00</xmp:CreateDate>
  <xmp:ModifyDate>2011-02-10T11:41:06+02:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
</rdf:Description></rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
<?xpacket end="w"?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!!   :)
My PDF is currently created by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile and the resulting PDF is "firstDoc.pdf". How can I make it such that I can pass this file in and add metadata to it?

Your code creates a new graphic context and use it to generate pdf.

Comment: When you generate the context, just use everything from the string down to the metadata addition call and pass in your context.  Also, don't forget to upvote and accept!

Comment: My problem is that I have multiple pages in the PDF document. I'm not sure about your method but the last when I was generating PDF I was unable to keep putting in strings. I have to call a some "create new page function" when I estimate that I am running out of page space.

Comment: The metadata applies to the _document_ not a page, so call it once and you're set for life.

Comment: Got it. Will try it out.

By the way... How do I retrieve the "hello world" string and XMP stuff from the pdf? Will I be able to see them by viewing the properties of the PDF doc on the Adobe Reader?

Comment: Another question... I have seen your sample XMP. Can I know how do I put these XMP content into the codes? Do I have to refer it to a file or I can just paste the XMP contents into the code. Sorry to ask so many questions I am still very new to iOS programming.

Comment: Use NSString's `+stringWithContentsOfFile` to load it in there.  Google around.

Comment: I have tried this method to write the meta into the pdf file but when I open it with another metadata reader I kept getting an error saying Line: 1 <?xml version=1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"

Comment: Solved the problem by cleaning and rebuilding the app.

Comment: How do you read the metadata back out of the PDF that was added with this code: CGPDFContextAddDocumentMetadata(graphicContext, cfdata); ?

Comment: How to embed annotations to pdf file?

Answer (score 1):

UIKit has some methods that make this simpler:

```
// use your own rect instead
CGRect pageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 600);

// mark the PDF as coming from your program
NSDictionary *auxillaryInformation = @{(NSString *)kCGPDFContextCreator: @"Koedal, Inc."};
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile([[self URLOfPDF] path], pageRect, auxillaryInformation);


// Embed metadata into PDF, I'm pulling it from a textView
NSString *PDFMetadata = self.metadataTextView.text;
NSData *data = [PDFMetadata  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

CGContextRef PDFContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGPDFContextAddDocumentMetadata(PDFContext, (CFDataRef)data);

NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20],
                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]
                                  };

// do your drawing, like drawing this string
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
NSString *content = self.contentTextField.text;
[content drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(150, 280) withAttributes:textAttributes];

// end your drawing
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Comment: Hi Collin, do you figure out, how to read the added metadata? I was trying use CGPDFDocumentGetInfo -> CGPDFDictionaryGetObject methods, but with no results.